# Euler notation of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

If I use the Euler notation for a complex number, then a complex number $z$ can the following exponential form:

$$e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^x e^{iy}=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)$$

So $e^x$ and $y$ represent the module and the angle of polar form of $z$, respectively?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Ok, but what if I multiply $e^z$ by, say, $\alpha=\frac{1}{3}(cos(-\frac{\pi}{3})+isen(-\frac{\pi}{3}))$, i.e., a number in polar form, how do I get the polar form again? Will it be just $\alpha z=\frac{1}{3}e^x(cos(y-\frac{\pi}{3})+isen(y-\frac{\pi}{3}))?$. I need to get the cartesian coordinates of this and it just doesn't seems right to me.

Comment: @A.Mello: Yeap! It is right!

Comment: @A.Mello $e^{i \pi/2}$ is the Euler form of $z=i$ and not of $z=i\pi/2$.

Comment: @Any So if $z=x+iy=|z|(cos \theta + i sen \theta)=|z|e^{i \theta}$, what's the point in having $e^x$ as module of $z = x+iy$?

Comment: @A.Mello The modulus of $0+1×i $ is  $e^0=1$.

Comment: That is, $z $ is represented by $re^{i \theta}$ if $r=|z|$ and $\theta = arg (z)$.

Comment: But you may want to ignore these comments, if I have misundrstood your question